# Зачем обозначать переменную словом let , если код работает и без этого?

Tags: javascript

Зачем обозначать переменную словом let , если код работает и без этого ?

Comment: Советую прочесть статью про [переменные](https://learn.javascript.ru/variables), там рассказано что такое `let`, почему он используется вместо `var` и почему используются `let` или `var` для назначения переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во первых, зависит от мода: "use strict" vs отсутствие "use strict".
Если его нет, то создание такой переменной создаст глобальное свойство объекта window, а проблемы которые это создаёт очевидные - начинают появляться коллизии имён глобальных свойств и приложение становится довольно хрупким.
Далее, если "use strict" присутствует, то он банально не даст использовать переменную без инициализации.

Answer (score 0):

`var` - имеет глобальную область видимости (на всё приложение)

`let, const`  - это переменные, которые видно только в пределах блока

```
function f() {
 const a = 'a';
 let b = 'b';
 var c = 'c';

 //какой-то код...
}

//тут переменных a и b, уже нет, но переменная с всё ещё видна глобально
```

В настоящее время не принято использовать `var` - это приводит к багам и считается плохим тоном.

Используйте только `const` и если вы знаете, что эту переменную нужно будет переопределить ниже в коде - тогда `let`

Comment: и let может быть глобальным если написать его за функцией - var можно переименовать а let и const нет

Comment: @Denys, вы что-то путаете. В вашем примере `c` - локальная переменная, она недоступна извне контекста функции `f`. Использование `var` не ведет ни к каким багам, пока вы понимаете, что делаете. @MaximLensky - что такое переименование переменных?)

Comment: @Yugofx опечатался не переименование а изменение